# Why is my custom module giving a "page not found" message when using https?

Tags: 7, hooks, ssl

I have a custom module that is a form. The first section in the hook_form() function is

```
if (!$_SERVER['HTTPS'] == 'on') {
    drupal_goto('https://mysite/mymodule');
}
```

If I comment out this section, the form works as expected. If the https redirect is left as is, I get a page not found error. This occurs only for unauthenticated users. If I am logged in, the form displays correctly.

I am on Drupal 6

EDIT: I turned off caching on my Drupal site and the form works again. The caching must have broken my form. I will see if I can find a way to not allow the form to be cached by Drupal.

Comment: Do you have SSL turned on and configured for your domain? Can you get to `https://mysite/mymodule` through the browser normally?

Comment: im not sure but you may need to take a look at your .htaccess file too

Comment: @Clive Yes, SSL is working everywhere else on the site. I can login to the admin part of the site through SSL no problem. When I try to hit the page through `https://mysite/mymodule`, it gives me the page not found error. Hitting the same site with `http://` redirects to the https URL and gives the same error.

Comment: @Sohail what sort of configuration should I be looking for in .htaccess?

Answer (score 0):

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}
```

or take a look at this [article](http://www.drupalcommerce.org/discussions/1063/httpsssl-redirect-using-htaccess)